# Server does not receive serialized objects through ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, android, servlets, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm writing an Android client that sends serialized "BuyListing" objects to my http servlet. I'm using an ObjectOutputStream to send from client and ObjectInputStream to receive on the server. When the server receives the serialized object, it tries to recognize it as a BuyListing using instanceof, and then sorts it from there.

My current implementation works fine when I pass a string through the objectstream, but when I pass my BuyListing object, the object I get on the server side is just "null". I canat figure out why this happens, and I suspect it might be something to do with serialization that I am not understanding.

Here is my clientside code to send the BuyListing object

```
  public static void sendListing(final Object inputListing)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
              Log.d("LOUD AND CLEAR", "Starting new thread for client/server connect with Listing support");
              try{
               URL url = new URL("http://myserverURL");
               URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();


               connection.setDoOutput(true);

               //Begin to open a new OutputObjectStream

               ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
               objectOut.writeObject(inputListing);


               objectOut.close();

               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
               String returnString="";
               doubledValue = "";

                        while ((returnString = in.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            doubledValue= returnString;
                          Log.d("LOUD AND CLEAR", doubledValue);
                        }
                        in.close();

                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                        }
                }
              }).start();
        }
```

Here is my server side receiving code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        int length = request.getContentLength();
        ServletInputStream sin = request.getInputStream();

        ObjectInputStream osin = new ObjectInputStream(sin);    //ObjectInputStream is created from our inputstream, and allows us to pass serialized objects



     // The following segment of code is used to transmit listings through the Object Streams
        // Read an object
        Object inputObject = null;
        String receivedString = " Server received a Listing";
        try {
            inputObject = osin.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (inputObject instanceof BuyListing)
        {
            // Cast object to a sellListing
            BuyListing inputBuyListing = (BuyListing) inputObject;
            SDB.submitBuyListing(inputBuyListing);
            receivedString = "Server received a BuyListing";
        }
        else if (inputObject instanceof String)
        {
            String out = (String) inputObject;
            receivedString = "Server found a string:" + out;    
        }
        else 
        {
            String temp = (String) inputObject;         
            receivedString =  "Server did not recognize object as a listing:" + temp;   
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());

        String outputValue = receivedString + " was received by Server";

        writer.write(outputValue.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        try{
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
            response.getWriter().close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }   
    }
```

My BuyListing object extends this Listing object

```
public abstract class Listing implements Serializable{ 

//the following variables need to be set when we create a new listing from the backend
    private int swipeCount; 
    private User user;
    private Venue venue; //might need to change this to just a string
    private String time;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    public String section;
    public Boolean isSection;

    //Getters and setters...
```

Where Venue and User are also serialized objects
Here is User

```
package sharedObjects;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class User implements Serializable{

private String name;
private String idNumber;
private String connections;
private String rating;

public User(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.idNumber = "undefined";
    this.connections = "undefined";
    this.rating = "undefined";


}
//setters + getters...
```

Venue Object

```
package sharedObjects;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Venue implements Serializable{

private String name;

public Venue(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
//Setters and Getters...
```

The BuyListing object right now is empty apart from extending Listing
    package sharedObjects;

```
/**
 * Item definition including the section.
 */
public class BuyListing extends Listing {

}
```

Anyway, I can successfully pass a string into ConnectToServer.sendListing and it'll work, but not when I pass a BuyListing object.

I've also read somewhere that classes aren't identical if they are in different packages. I'm not sure exactly what that means but both my server and client side have packages named "sharedObjects" where I keep the serialized object classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> when I pass my BuyListing object, the object I get on the server side is just "null"

If you received a null you sent a null.